# Audits should not include can't-be-reproduced/typo closures

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Recently ran into [a first post audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6526192) for a question on SO that was closed (and deleted) as being caused either by a typo or some sort of heisenbug. I don't know which, but the important thing is that there is, by definition, no way to tell in review that a question is no longer reproducible without manually checking to see if it's still open. And even typos are often quite subtle for any but a subject expert to spot.

Therefore, it seems like including this close reason in audits tends to basically be nothing but a test of whether you're detecting audits proactively. Which, while technically requiring attention of some sort, is not actually testing the sort of attention that's useful for reviewing posts, per se.

Comment: Did the answer not show up for you?

Comment: This seems like a bad audit to me, but not for the reason you have given. I wouldn't have closed.

Comment: @JanDvorak I had and have no way to see the answer at all, then or now. All I had to go on was the question, and it set off no particular red flags, so I didn't open it in a new tab to check that.

Comment: Then it's a bug. Answers deleted with the question should be shown when the question is used as an audit.

Comment: @JanDvorak, that would certainly help, although it might look a bit odd, I guess.